# prevent applying join() method when string is empty- Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string that i want to concatenate with other string.

```
var str="abc, test, addres";

str.split(",").concat("add_something").join(","); // this gives - str="abc, test, addres, add_something";
```

however now there can be a scenario where my str could be empty, like `""`. in such case when I try to `concat` and `join` I get this as output.

`",add_something"` the comma gets added in front.

NOTe: "`add_something`" is like default value I want to always append at the end of string.

is there a way we can handle this scenario where when str is empty I still want to concatenate, however not `join` and use `join` only when str has value?
thx

Comment: Just check string length first, return default only if no length, otherwise do the split

Comment: array.join can't do that, but you can use your own wrapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about This?

```
let str="abc, test,, addres,,";
let joined = str.split(",").filter(str => str != "").concat('add_something').join(", ");
 
console.log(joined);
```

Comment: it's same thing Mister!

Comment: And you can use `.filter(Boolean)` instead of  `.filter(str => str != "")` , as I do...

Comment: Yeah thats true. he wrote this: NOTE: "add_something" is like default value I want to always append at the end of string

Answer (score 1):

What you may have to do is sort through the array afterwards

```js
let str = "abc, test, addres,, sdfdsf,,";

str.split(",").concat("add_something").join(",");

console.log(str);

//convert back to array
str = str.split(",");

//fiter out empty strings and convert back to string (empty strings are considered falsey)
str = str.filter(value => value).join(",");

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

simply:

```js
let str = 'abc, test, addres'  

str.split(',').concat('add_something').filter(Boolean).join(',')
```

or maybe with a wrapper (or two) ?

```js
// Array.joinStr  wrapper
if (!Array.prototype.joinStr) { Array.prototype.joinStr = function(s='') {
    return this.filter(Boolean).join(s)
} }

// Array.join2noEmptyStr  wrapper
if (!String.prototype.join2noEmptyStr) { String.prototype.join2noEmptyStr = function(addStr,cut=',',sep=',') {
    return this.split(cut).reduce((a,c)=>{c=c.trim();if(!!c) a.push(c);return a},[]).concat(addStr).join(sep)
} }

var arr=['aa','', 'bb']; arr[15]= 'xx';
let str = 'abc, test, addres'  

console.log("arr.join(',') ->",     arr.join(','), '(for info)' ) // aa,,bb,,,,,,,,,,,,,xx
console.log("arr.joinStr(',') ->",  arr.joinStr(',') )           // aa,bb,xx
console.log('------------')
console.log('join2noEmptyStr ->', str.join2noEmptyStr('add_something',',',', ') ) // abc, test, addres, add_something
```